# Is "where" a relative pronoun or a relative adverb?

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-clauses, relative-adverbs

> *He lives in a village where there are no shops.*
>   When *who*, *which*, *where*, etc are used in this way, they are called **relative pronouns**.

*Michael Swan, Practical English Usage fourth edition, Section 21*

> *the hotel where they were staying*
>   *When*, *where* and *why* used in this way are called **relative adverbs**.

*A.J. Thomson & A.V. Martinet, A Practical English Grammar fourth edition, Page 83*

I believe Swan has loosely classified all these relative words as relative pronouns and *A Practical English Grammar* is more accurate there. What do you think?

Comment: "Where" is not a relative pronoun. We have 5 relative pronouns: which, that, whose, who, whom. Technically, it's a subordinate conjunction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swan categorizes the word according to its referent, Thomson & Martinet categorize it according to its syntactic role. Neither categorization tells you much that's useful, and both reveal the inadequacy of the traditional 'part-of-speech' approach.

In its core use, designating the location or goal of an entity or action, *where* is neither a pronoun nor a [pro]adverb but a *pro-PP*—that is, it 'stands for' a **preposition phrase** constructed with

- **a)** an unspecified-but-inferrable preposition—in your first sentence it's *in*, in your second it's *at*—and
- **b)** an unspecified-but-inferrable relative *which*

> 1. a village **where** there are no shops = a village **in which** there are no shops
> 2. the hotel **where** they were staying = The hotel **at which** they were staying

In these cases Swan's categorization is clearly inadequate, and T&M's categorization may or may not be accurate: locative PPs do not always act as 'adverbs' modifying clauses. In 2., for instance, the PP represented by *where* should probably be regarded as a locative complement, not an adverbial.

And there are also uses of *where* to designate the origin of an entity or event; here *where* has to be supplemented by an express preposition such as *from*:

> The town where he comes from . . .

In informal registers this supplementary preposition is often extended to 'core' locative and goal uses:

> Come on, come on, let me tell you where it's at

In such cases *where* may be described as a relative 'pronoun' with regard to its referent, and in most cases it will act as a locative complement rather than as an adverb.

Comment: This is good stuff. We need an analogue of the gerpapple here.